Is My Magnetic Sensor-Activated Power Switch Circuit with Dual P-Channel MOSFETs Correctly Configured?
Is This Magnetic Sensor-Activated Power Switch Circuit Correctly Configured?
I'm working on a circuit designed to control power using a magnetic sensor and two P-channel MOSFETs. The magnetic sensor outputs high when the magnet is not present and low when it is. The goal is to activate the first P-channel MOSFET when the magnet is present, which should turn on the power to the circuit. The second MOSFET is also a P-channel type, but its gate is connected through an inverter to the status pin (STAT) of a battery charging IC (MCP73831T). The STAT pin pulls low during charging, and this should turn off the power from the magnetic switch, even if the magnet is present.
Here’s a summary of how I expect the circuit to operate:

Normal Operation: When the magnet is present, the first MOSFET should turn on, supplying power to the circuit. The second MOSFET should allow the charging IC to operate normally.

Charging State: During charging, the STAT pin goes low, which, after inversion, should turn off the second MOSFET, cutting off the power to the rest of the circuit, even if the magnet is present.

Idle State: When not charging, the STAT pin is slightly pulled high, which should allow the second MOSFET to remain open, thus keeping the power on when the magnet is present.


I've attached a schematic for reference. Could someone please review this and let me know if the configuration is correct? I'm particularly concerned about whether the second MOSFET will behave as expected during the different operating states.
Additional Context:

The charging IC is intended for a button battery.
The circuit should ensure that power is cut off when charging is active to prevent interference.
The magnetic sensor is configured to control the power to the circuit based on the presence of a magnet.

Is there anything I might be missing in this configuration, or could there be potential issues with how the MOSFETs are controlled?

